# Decryption method for encryption method in Python

Tags: python, encryption, base64

I am looking for decryption method for this encryption algorithm

```
import base64
characterEncoding = 'utf-8'
def encrypt(str, key):
    strBytes = bytearray(str.encode(characterEncoding))
    keyBytes = bytearray(key.encode(characterEncoding))
    off = -128;
    for i in range(len(strBytes)):
        off += strBytes[i]
        strBytes[i] = (off ^ keyBytes[i % len(keyBytes)]) & 0xFF
    return base64.b64encode(strBytes).decode(characterEncoding)
```

This code that I wrote as I was trying to solve it but I am not sure about the logic of what I did

```
def decrypt(str, key):
    strcipher = bytearray(base64.b64decode(str))
    keyBytes = bytearray(key.encode(characterEncoding))
    for i in range(len(strcipher)):
        on = (strcipher[i] ^ keyBytes[i % len(keyBytes)]) & 0xFF
        strcipher[i] = on - strcipher[i+1]

    return strcipher.decode('utf-8')`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you already try some code? If so, would you share it?

Comment: Yes, I tried many things but I can't find the correct logic to reverse the encryption. This is the last code I tried. @FrancescoB.

Comment: please [edit] your question instead of putting code in comments.

Comment: I edit my post please check it!